# ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS on selenium phantomjs

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, httpclient, ghostdriver

Hi with this code i can say to DefaultHttpClient, hey use this interfaceip for connection. So how can i say like this to phantomjsdriver.
note: sorry for my english. not my native language

Example:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient;

try {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS, InetAddress.getByName(interfaceIp));

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS, InetAddress.getByName(interfaceIp));
this.driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```